# Excel 2003 VBA method "cells" run-time error

Tags: excel, runtime-error, excel-2003, vba

> run-time error '1004': "cells" method of object '_global' failed

```
numShips=7
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Ship Tracker").Range(Cells(2,78),Cells(17, NumShips+80)),_
PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

Why did I get this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (you haven't specify sheet to which `Cells()` belongs):

```
NumShips = 7
With Sheets("Ship Tracker")
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(2, 78), .Cells(17, NumShips + 80)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
End With
```

Comment: I get a compile error: invalid or unqualified reference  if I do that

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you use _all_ code from my asnwer (especially `With` block)?